# java -cp option doesn't work if files are not in current directory

Tags: java

I have a Spring Boot app which contains `myService.properties` file in resource folder (so it's copied into the classpath). This property files has all the properties empty. I have JAR file generated. I want to overwrite the properties, so I created my own `myService.properties` file. I run it from command line:

```
 directory=$HOME/apps/myApp/files

 java <VM ptions>
      -cp ".:$directory/jar/myJar.jar:$directory/config/myService.properties" \
      -Dloader.main=<Path to main class> org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

When I run this, the app complains that properties in `myService.properties` are empty (thus the original property file is considered).

However, when I copy the properties file to current directory and call it using:

```
 directory=$HOME/apps/myApp/files

 java <VM ptions>
      -cp ".:$directory/jar/myJar.jar:myService.properties" \
      -Dloader.main=<Path to main class> org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

Everything works as it should. Why doesn't the `-cp` option load files that are not in current directory?

Does it mean that the classpath contains `myService.properties` contained in my JAR file but also `myService.properties` that I include in the classpath, however with whole path, e.g.

`$HOME/apps/myApp/files/config/myService.properties` and when the app look for the config file it first finds the `myService.properties` included in JAR file and not the one I include in classpath?

If so is the only way to fix this to exclude `myService.properties` from JAR file or just have `myService.properties` in current directory?

Comment: That's because you've included the properties file *itself* in the classpath. There's no such thing as a file being part of a classpath, *unless* that file happens to be a jar. You need the *directory that contains the properties file* in the classpath, not the file itself. So: `-cp ".:$directory/jar/myJar.jar:$directory/config"`

Comment: same error, and also you can directly include files using -cp.

Comment: Can you please show *literally* what you're running instead of using placeholders

Comment: The `.` means current folder. That's the only thing that's currently working. I would try putting an `echo` in front of the `java` command. Make sure it's expanding as you expect.

Comment: That's a good plan

Comment: @g00se Technically it doesn't have to be a JAR file, any ZIP file should do.

Comment: As g00se says, you cannot just include non-JAR/ZIP files in the classpath. You can only specify directories or archives containing class and other files. The fact it works if you move it into the current directory is because with `.` you added the file on the classpath (and *before* the JAR, generally the classpath is evaluated in the specified order, though I don't believe that is actually guaranteed).

Comment: *.. any ZIP file should do ..* that could be the case. Not sure if that's *always* been the case though `-D"spring.messages.basename=$directory/config"` might also work *if* it's expanding properly

Comment: @g00se I think that worked from the start. In the past, I have seen some applications and libraries distributed with the JAR actually having a `.zip` suffix, and putting those on the classpath worked. In any case, assuming your suggestion is correct, I think it should be `"-Dspring.messages.basename=$directory/config"` (quotes around the entire option), to avoid issues with commandline parsers.

Comment: Yes, I think your version is better

Answer (score 2):

The classpath is a list Java archives or directories that contain "exploded" archives. You can't add arbitrary files.

The first example doesn't work because the directory that contains `myService.properties` is not on the classpath. (`$directory/config/myService.properties` doesn't count; it's not a directory.)

The second example works because the directory that contains the file is in the classpath before the other copy (`.`, the current working directory).

Comment: actual [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/man/java.html#standard-options-for-java): "... Specifies a list of directories, JAR files, and ZIP archives to search for class files. ..."

Comment: when i include only `$directory/config` or `$directory/config/` the problem remains the same

Comment: @Johnyb Are you putting it first in the classpath?

Comment: @erickson yes and it does not work